# sending mails with GAE local environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I can't find how to send emails in my local project without deploying.
I can't set the sender email, the method does nothing...

```
class MailHandler(BaseHandler):
def get(self):
    message = mail.EmailMessage()
    message.sender = 'my@email.com'
    message.to = 'some@email.com'
    message.subject = 'test'
    message.body = "Email test, that's all."
    message.send()
    self.render_ok()
```

Comment: It's normal. The devserver doesn't "touch" internet. How would it send email?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your Appengine launcher [edit->application settings] with the following command-line arguments:

`--enable_sendmail`
`--smtp_host=...`
`--smtp_port=...`
`--smtp_user=...`
`--smtp_password=...`

See:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Command-line_arguments

For testing, setting up a local mail server is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Mail_and_the_development_server) explains what you're looking for.  By default it does nothing but log the message contents.

Comment: Note: If you use sendmail, your test mails will be classed as spam by nearly every filter.

Answer (score 0):

Unittests collect sent messages in the stub and can be printed out, or tested, during/after a test like this:

```
class EmailTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_mail_stub()

    def tearDown(self):
        mail_stub = self.testbed.get_stub(testbed.MAIL_SERVICE_NAME)
        for message in mail_stub.get_sent_messages():
            print message.body
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def test_mailhandler(self):
        # put your tests here. something like
        MailHandler().get()
```

[As described here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_mail_tests)